# Query optimization needed, the original is taking to long when using 'IN' and 'OR/AND' in the query, I believe union will take even longer

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hue

I am trying to get the best performance out of this query, the Table has 27 million records, but the result will contain only 160 records when I use the below where clause. This is a view. Original table is partitioned by emp_dept. Parallel reading is not application for my use case because this view's data will be refreshed everyday to get the data for past 24 months.

```
SELECT
a.fname,
a.lname,
a.mname,
a.emp_id,
a.emp_dob,
a.emp_dept
FROM emp.emp_profile a
WHERE a.emp_join_dt BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-01 00:00:00'
AND a.emp_salary BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
AND ((a.emp_id = '0000000024Z67089' AND a.emp_dept= 'INV' AND a.emp_div = '293') 
    OR (a.emp_id = '000000008UK23197' AND a.emp_dept = 'INV' AND a.emp_div = '293') 
    OR (a.emp_id = '000000006JF10942' AND a.emp_dept = 'INV' AND a.emp_div = '293')
    OR (a.emp_id = '5B103B51' AND a.emp_dept = 'IPS' AND a.emp_div = '640')
    OR (a.emp_id = '0000000016H79794' AND a.emp_dept = 'INV' AND a.emp_div = '293'));
```

I have tried using 'IN':

```
SELECT
a.fname,a.lname,a.mname,a.emp_id,a.emp_dob,a.emp_dept
FROM emp.emp_profile a
WHERE (a.emp_join_dt BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-01 00:00:00')
AND (a.emp_salary BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000) AND a.emp_id in    ('0000000024Z67089', '000000008UK23197', '000000006JF10942', '0000000016H79794', '5B103B51')  
AND a.emp_dept in ('INV','IPS') 
AND a.emp_div in ('293', '640');

*This gives me the same count and better query time, but it is still over 1.5 minute.*
```

Union All will take even more time, I think, one which I have tired didn't gave me correct result.

Trying to get the querytime under 1 min, if possible.

Comment: Your second query will give you a different result so it's not comparable. Instead `WHERE  a.emp_join_dt BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-01 00:00:00'
AND a.emp_salary BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000 AND ((a.emp_id in ('0000000024Z67089', '000000008UK23197', '000000006JF10942', '0000000016H79794') AND a.emp_dept= 'INV' AND a.emp_div = '293') OR (a.emp_id = '5B103B51' AND a.emp_dept = 'IPS' AND a.emp_div = '640'))` but like your test you *may* not see much improvement. Why not try the union?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `emp_join_dt` and `emp_div`?

Comment: Using UNION should give you the best performance in the above scenario. Always try to avoid OR conditions in your JOIN statements.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the DDL statement for your table. I'd guess that `emp_join_dt` is of type DATE or TIMESTAMP and  `emp_div` is numeric; if that's true, using strings in your `WHERE` clauses might cause unnecessary conversions and/or prevent the usage of indices.

Comment: Which columns are indexed?

Comment: I tried union with some of the clauses, it took longer, May b i m not doing it right.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman I dont have indexes on any columns.

Comment: @Frank schmitt, dt is in string and salary in decimal.

Comment: Please provide the View code as well, maybe there is something that can be optimized